# How to find unique value range between two values and fill in

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let me start off with the caveat that I'm new to the site and newer to coding, so hopefully, the formating of this all displays correctly.

I looking to locate a few given unique records in a data set (in example data "blah4" and "blah44") and update the value below their location up to the location of the other unique record I flagged. I've tried searching on this topic but haven't had much luck yet. Any help/direction that you could provide would be much appreciated. Cheers!

```
    import pandas as pd

    info = [("blah1","blah2","blah3"),
           ("blah4","blah5","blah6"),
           ("blah11","blah22","blah33"),
           ("blah44","blah55","blah66"),
           ("blah7","blah8","blah9"),
           ("blah77","blah88","blah99")]

           df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns =["Name","Type","Class"])
           print(df)

       #Highlighting the data values that I'm looking to locate and use to replace values beneth untill reaching the next data value  
       print(df[df[:].isin(["blah4","blah44"])])

       #Desired outcome 
       info2 = [("blah1","blah2","blah3"),
                ("blah4","blah5","blah6"),
                ("blah4","blah22","blah33"),
                ("blah44","blah55","blah66"),
                ("blah44","blah8","blah9"),
                ("blah44","blah88","blah99")]
       df2 = pd.DataFrame(info2, columns =["Name","Type","Class"])
       print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `cumsum` and `transform`:

```
df["Name"] = df.groupby(df["Name"].isin(["blah4","blah44"]).cumsum())["Name"].transform("first")

print (df)

     Name    Type   Class
0   blah1   blah2   blah3
1   blah4   blah5   blah6
2   blah4  blah22  blah33
3  blah44  blah55  blah66
4  blah44   blah8   blah9
5  blah44  blah88  blah99
```